# How to add a user to 80 Active Directory groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I can pull the list of groups using this this snipppet:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "*.ABC*"}
```

How can I add a user to the returned groups?

Comment: Have you tried [`Add-ADGroupMember`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2019-ps)?

Comment: Correction, I am using this script to pull a list of the groups. Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "*.ABC*"}

Comment: Use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69437769/edit) if you need to modify your existing question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could push the results from the command in your question to a variable and then run a foreach loop that will add the member for each group within the variable.

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -like "*.ABC*"}

foreach ($group in $groups){
  Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members User1
}
```

Comment: OK I am trying this now.